# certificate verify failed OAuth2

Tags: python, django

I am using the code below to get a token to access the Google Calendar API. I'm not sure why I keep getting the following error:

```
[Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed.
```

traceback:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  20.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/aribaaboobakar/djcode/newProj/books/views.py" in auth_return
  67.   credential = FLOW.step2_exchange(request.REQUEST)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google_api_python_client-1.2-py2.7.egg/oauth2client/util.py" in positional_wrapper
  132.       return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google_api_python_client-1.2-py2.7.egg/oauth2client/client.py" in step2_exchange
  1283.                                  headers=headers)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.9-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py" in request
  1593.                     (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.9-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py" in _request
  1335.         (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.9-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py" in _conn_request
  1257.                     conn.connect()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.9-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py" in connect
  1044.                     raise SSLHandshakeError(e)

Exception Type: SSLHandshakeError at /oauth2callback
Exception Value: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

---

```
def index(request):
 storage = Storage(CredentialsModel, 'id', request.user, 'credential')
  credential = storage.get()
  if credential is None or credential.invalid == True:
    FLOW.params['state'] = xsrfutil.generate_token(settings.SECRET_KEY,
                                                   request.user)
    authorize_url = FLOW.step1_get_authorize_url()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(authorize_url)
  else:
    http = httplib2.Http(disable_ssl_certificate_validation=True)
    http = credential.authorize(http)
    service = build("plus", "v1", http=http)
    activities = service.activities()
    activitylist = activities.list(collection='public',
                                   userId='me').execute()
    logging.info(activitylist)

    return render_to_response('plus/welcome.html', {
                'activitylist': activitylist,
                })
```

---

```
@login_required
def auth_return(request):
  if not xsrfutil.validate_token(settings.SECRET_KEY, request.REQUEST['state'],
                                 request.user):
    return  HttpResponseBadRequest()
  credential = FLOW.step2_exchange(request.REQUEST)
  storage = Storage(CredentialsModel, 'id', request.user, 'credential')
  storage.put(credential)
  return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

Answer (score 0):

The error  `SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed`  is almost always  caused by having an incorrect `system time` set on your computer or your  `CA is out-of-date and needs to be updated`.

Check that your `time and date` on your computer is correct.

Comment: im on a mac and went to system preferences. the date and time are correct

Comment: try `http = httplib2.Http(disable_ssl_certificate_validation=True)` and post the full traceback, this is not a fix, disabling cert verification is not a good idea, I just want to see if it works

Comment: also what does `python -c "import ssl; print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION"` output?

Comment: OpenSSL 0.9.7l 28 Sep 2006

Comment: added traceback above